# Send JSON request with Restkit RKParams

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I need to send a JSON request to a REST service. I'm using Restkit RKParams to send a request.

Currently it works as follows:

```
[params setValue:@"-46.566393" forParam:@"checkin[lng]"]; 
[params setValue:@"-23.541576" forParam:@"checkin[lat]"];
```

Send:

```
{
    "checkin":
    {
        "lng":"-26.566393",
        "lat":"-63.541576"
    }
}
```

Now I want to form JSON data like this (with few more items):

```
{
    "checkin":
    {
        "lng":"-26.566393",
        "lat":"-63.541576",
        "votes":
        [
            {"vote_id":28},
            {"vote_id":11}
        ]
    }
}
```

How would I set the params to work as desired? It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RestKit does handle nested models, but it looks like it doesn't do that directly in RKParams. I would look at some of the other classes to do what you're trying to do. [Key-value mapping](https://github.com/twotoasters/RestKit/blob/master/Examples/RKCatalog/Examples/RKKeyValueMappingExample/RKKeyValueMappingExample.m) looks like it will do what you want.

Or if you want to hack it,

```
[RKParams setValue:@"[{\"vote_id\":28},{\"vote_id\":11}]" forParam:@"checkin[votes]"]
```

might just work. No promises, though.